# Emgu CV can't play video

Tags: c#, opencv, video, emgucv

I can't play play video with Emgu CV

It's show error

> Unable to create capture from 184.avi

Here is the code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //Set the name of pop-up window
    String winname = "First Window";
    Timer My_Time = new Timer();
    int FPS=30;
    Capture _capture;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    //Frame Rate
    My_Timer.Interval = 1000 / FPS;
    My_Timer.Tick += new EventHandler(My_Timer_Tick);
    My_Timer.Start();

    _capture = new Capture("184.avi");   // Error this line

    }

    private void My_Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        imageBox.Image = _capture.QueryFrame().ToBitmap();
    }
```

I use windows 8 x64 and install `emgucv-windows-universal-cuda 2.4.10.1940` It have no `opencv_ffmpeg.dll` in bin. So I install opencv-2.4.11 and copy all dll from OpenCV bin to paste in Debug in my project. I paste 184.avi to Debug too. But when I run it show error like this. How to play video with Emgu CV?

Comment: Hope this helps. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/722569/Video-Capture-using-OpenCV-with-Csharp

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine. I think the problem is that you have not imported the video file to Visual Studio. So try importing the video file to visual studio and also set the properties to copy always. You can see below that i have imported the A.avi file and set it's properties to copy always.

[image]

And think you can just use `imageBox.Image = _capture.QueryFrame();` instead of `imageBox.Image = _capture.QueryFrame().ToBitmap();`because you don't need to convert to bitmap with ImageBox.

The code i used is same as yours.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.CvEnum;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.CV.UI;
using Emgu.CV.Features2D;
using Emgu.CV.Util;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {//Set the name of pop-up window
        String winname = "First Window";
        Timer My_Time = new Timer();
        int FPS = 30;
        Capture _capture;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //Frame Rate
            My_Time.Interval = 1000 / FPS;
            My_Time.Tick += new EventHandler(My_Timer_Tick);
            My_Time.Start();

            _capture = new Capture("A.avi");   // Error this line

        }

        private void My_Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            imageBox.Image = _capture.QueryFrame();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I try every thing but it still have error 
NullReferenceException was unhandled
**Unable to create capture from 184.avi**  I don't know how to fix this problem.

Comment: For me it first gave the same error and it was fixed after importing the video file to visual studio. Try checking Emgu Cv configurations with Visual Studio with this. https://notebookbft.wordpress.com/2015/03/08/setting-up-emgu-cv-project-with-visual-studio/

Answer (score 0):

You can just provide full path instead of just the file name.

You do not have the video file in the same folder as your program exe. 
If you place video file just next to your program exe, it should also work.